# Generate specific XMLGregorianCalendar format and convert it to normalize

Tags: java

How can I convert a date to XMLGregorianCalendar with this format: "2020-01-01T14:32:09+1000" to this format "2020-01-01T14:32:09.000Z"

```
public static XMLGregorianCalendar getDate(XMLGregorianCalendar date) {
    date.setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
    return date;
}

Input = "2020-01-01T14:32:09+1000" // This is XMLGregorianCalendar but I couldn't generate it in this format
output = "2020-01-01T14:32:09.000Z" // This is what I need
```

Maybe the method is OK and the only I need to change is the input format but I tried a lot of things and I wasn't able to do it.

Thanks

Comment: The input is coming from a third party library query... so I can't manipulate it. For unit test I need to simulate what is coming from this third party library

Comment: Are you looking to convert this XMLGregorianFormat to a DateTime (ISO Format)?

Comment: That input date is coming from a MQ and I need to covert it into the output format to push it to another MQ which accepts that format